# HTML img src returning a 404 not found error

Tags: html, css, http-status-code-404, src

I have this piece of code and I do not understand why I can not get the image on my site, can anyone help?

```
<img src = "/ API-joana / API-joana / api2 / images / home1.jpg" style = "width: 100%">
```

I have this piece of code implemented inside the templates folder, in one of the html files I have.

Folders:

```
- API - joana
  - API -joana
    - api2
      - imagens
        - template
          - teste.py
```

Comment: Try removing white spaces. If they exist add in the %20 to represent them. In your folder structure you have imagens vs images in your path (typo?)

Comment: Or if white spaces exist, add in the %20 where they're missing. "API - joana" is not the same as "API-joana"

Comment: @Doug 
In my code I did not have the spaces and I tried the piece of code that indicated but it does not work the same, what is the reason?

Comment: Quick test is to paste the URL in your image's src into a browser. (add in hostname and whatnot... http://www.google.com/API-Joana/...) If you can get the image to load paste the URL that resolves into your src

Answer (score 0):

The `src` attribute should contain a valid URL.since space characters are not allowed in URLs, you have to encode them.

For example if `space` exist in your folder names :

```
 <img src="/%20API-joana%20/%20API-joana%20/%20api2%20/%20images%20/%20home1.jpg">
```

or remove space from both link and folder names.